# TCP Data from Xamarin Android app corrupted

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, tcp, protobuf-net

I have a Xamarin Android app that captures h264 video frames from an Android 4.4 (KitKat) device (x86 hardware) and sends them via TCP to a Windows 10 client (via WiFi). I am using protobuf.net to package the frames with SerializeWithLengthPrefix (Fixed32). This works well most of the time but randomly (between 20 seconds and 10 minutes) the data on the receive side gets corrupted. You can see that I also save the data to the device for debugging. Reading this data using the client app does not produce any errors (it's not corrupted). I am at a loss as to where the issue is. It seems like a platform bug with Xamarin's TCP client, but I have a hard time believing that I would be the only one having this issue. Note: The TCP comm is working in it's own thread.

```
   private static void ProcessFrameQueue(TcpClient client)
        {
            //debug log for comparing TCP socket sent data with client recieved
            _tempDumpFile = StreamControl.GetOutputTempFilePath(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + "-probuf-dump.bin");

            var sentFrameCount = 0;
            try
            {

                while (client.Client.IsConnected())
                {
                    var data = _packetQueue.Take();
                    try
                    {
                        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                        {

                            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, data, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);
                            var protoBufData = stream.ToArray();
                            client.Client.Send(protoBufData);

                            //for debugging -- save the TCP data for comparison to what is recieved
                            //todo: delete as this is debuggng
                            using (var filestream = new FileStream(_tempDumpFile, FileMode.Append))
                            {
                                filestream.Write(protoBufData, 0, protoBufData.Length);
                                filestream.Flush(true);
                            }
                        }
                        sentFrameCount++;

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //log error

                    }
                } //end while

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               //log error
            }
        }
```

this is a simple client I wrote for debugging (I am manually calculating the packet size to make sure it's not an error in protobuf.net -- it's not a protobuf.net issue). Eventually the size packet will contain bad data leading to an overflow.

```
  var client = new TcpClient("x.x.x.x", 19901);
        client.ReceiveTimeout = 100000000;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        var netStream = client.GetStream();

        var sizezReadBtyes = 0;



        var sizeBytes = new byte[4];
        var packetCount = 0;
        while (true)
        {

            //reads until it gets 4 bytes to calculate the packet size
            var sizeOffset = 0;
            var sizeLength = 4;
            while ((sizezReadBtyes = netStream.Read(sizeBytes, sizeOffset, sizeLength)) > 0)
            {
                sizeOffset += sizezReadBtyes;
                sizeLength -= sizezReadBtyes;
            }

            //read the remaining data...
            var offset = 0;
            var packetBytes = 0;
            int packetlength = BitConverter.ToInt32(sizeBytes, 0);
            var buffer = new byte[packetlength];


            while (packetlength > 0 && (packetBytes = netStream.Read(buffer, offset, packetlength)) > 0)
            {
                offset += packetBytes;
                packetlength -= packetBytes;
            }
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            {
                var obj = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<NetworkMediaPacket>(ms);
                Console.WriteLine($"packet found {packetCount++} {obj.Data.Length}");
            }

            if (packetlength > 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();

        }
```

Comment: are you sure `while ((readBtyes = netStream.Read(sizeBytes, 0, 4)) > 0)` always reads 4 bytes? because you're only checking on `> 0` You might create a small while for reading the `Fixed32` header.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Thanks for the suggestion. I've added a check to the size read (see sample client), but it still results in intermittent errors.  Also, this code is just am alternative to ProtoBuf.Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix which also failed.

Comment: more digging indicates that the packets are sometimes overwritten by the next packet in the stream. I used packets filled with zero values (instead of the regular payload). so I can now see the next packet header being inserted in the inside the payload of the previous packet.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix by removing my Blocking Queue (_packetQueue). I just used a writeasync on a TCPClient NetStream. This looks to me like a bug in the Xamarin/Mono/.net code.